# How to measure a time of switching process context in Linux using C++?

Tags: c++, linux, process

I need to measure the time of context switching using C++. I know that I can simply access C-functions from C++ code, but the task is in avoiding C where it's possible. I have searched this in the Internet but found only ways to do this using C. Are there any ways to work with OS in C++? Any analogs of `pipe(...)` from `unistd.h`, `sched_setaffinity(...)` from `sched.h` and others?

Comment: All syscalls from [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are callable from C++ code (since C++ has been designed to be interoperable with C). And I am not sure you can measure *reliably* & *accurately* the time to make a context switch. This is not related to C or C++ language used.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch , thanks for your answer. I should measure it approximately, I think. Then I will use syscalls, thank you. I'm going to create two processes, set a high priority to them and measure the time of switching between them. Also, I found a tip about using multi-processor system on which one processor is employed for context switch measurement while the other runs OS background tasks. I hope all that will work correctly together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update 2017-06-30:  example code added

> ```
> Are there any ways to work with OS in C++?
> ```

All of the C functions you referenced are simply accessed by direct include.
example:

```
#include "pthread.h"
```

and in a C++ compile, auto-magically get extern "C"'d.

Your link will need -lrt and -pthread on Linux

```
Any analogs of pipe(...) from unistd.h, sched_setaffinity(...)
```

Not analogs, the build links to the real "C" Linux functions.

---

```
I need to measure the time of context switching using C++ means.
```

I measure durations by repeating some action for 1 to 10 seconds, and counting how many times the loop completes.

In my latest minor benchmark, *completely* written in C++ (but not using C++11 features), I

- build a linked list of nodes
- each node has its own thread
- each thread owns 2 pointers to pthread_mutex semaphores (input and output)
- each thread body waits for its input semaphore to be signaled (semTake())
- upon awakening, the thread body signals (semGive()) to its output semaphore and does 
  almost nothing more
- The N threads' semaphores are handed out to the node threads and the loop closed
  at the end of the list  (i.e. end-list-node output semaphore handle points to 
  begin-list-node input semaphore handle)
- The main task, starts the chain reaction with a semGive(), waits 10 seconds (using
  usleep), then sets a flag that every thread can see.

---

Example Run on 6 yr old Dell.

---

```
Compilation started at Wed Jan 15 22:31:33

./lmbm101
lmbm101: context-switch duration .. wait up to 10 seconds while measuring.
  switch enforced using pthread_mutex semaphores

C5   bogomips:  5210.77   5210.77  
  686.56  kilo  m_thread_switch invocations in 10.88 sec   (10000088 us)
  68.6554  kilo  m_thread_switch events per second
  14.5655  u seconds per m_thread_switch event
pid = 12188

now (52d760af): 22:31:43
bdtod 2014/01/15 22:31:43  minod=1351  iod=91  secod=81103  soi=104
```

---

I did this minor benchmark prior to C++11 release.  This code was compiled with C++11, but does not use the C++11 tasking ... a future effort for me.

---

update 2017-06-30 - overdue update ...

I wrote this example code 2017-04.  I now tend to use std::vector for various things. Previous measurements did not.  Similar techniques, but simplified result reporting.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// see EngFormat-Cpp-master.zip
#ifndef                 ENG_FORMAT_H_INCLUDED
#include "../../bag/src/eng_format.hpp"        // to_engineering_string(), from_engineering_string()
#endif

#include <cassert>


#include <semaphore.h>  // Note 1 - Ubuntu / Posix feature access, see PPLSEM_t


namespace DTB // doug's test box
{
   // Note 2 - typedefs to simplify chrono access
   // 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
   typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
   typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // std-chrono-hi-res-clk-time-point
   typedef std::chrono::microseconds           NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
   typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
   typedef std::chrono::microseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
   using   namespace std::chrono_literals;          // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us
   // examples:
   //   Time_t testStart_us = HRClk_t::now();
   //   auto  testDuration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - testStart_us);
   //   auto         count_us =       testDuration_us.count();
   //   or
   //   std::cout << "  complete " << testDuration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;



   // C++ access to Linux semaphore via Posix
   // Posix Process Semaphore, set to Local mode (unnamed, unshared)
   class PPLSem_t
   {
   public:               // shared-between-threads--v  v--initial-value is unlocked
      PPLSem_t()   { assert(0 == ::sem_init(&m_sem, 0, 1)); } // ctor
      ~PPLSem_t()  { assert(0 == ::sem_destroy(&m_sem));    } // dtor

      int lock()   { return (::sem_wait(&m_sem)); }   // returns 0 when success, else -1
      int unlock() { return (::sem_post(&m_sem)); }   // returns 0 when success, else -1

      void wait()  { assert(0 == lock());   }
      void post()  { assert(0 == unlock()); }

   private:
      ::sem_t m_sem;
   };
   // POSIX is an api, this C++ class simplifies use
   //    sem_wait and sem_post are possibly assembly for best performance



   // Note 3 - locale what now?
   // insert commas from right to left -- change 1234567890 to 1,234,567,890
   // input 's' is the digits-to-the-left-of-the-decimal-point
   // returns s contents with inserted comma's
   std::string digiComma(std::string s)
   {  //vvvvv--sSize must be signed int of sufficient size
      int32_t sSize = static_cast<int32_t>(s.size());
      if (sSize > 3)
         for (int32_t indx = (sSize - 3); indx > 0; indx -= 3)
            s.insert(static_cast<size_t>(indx), 1, ',');
      return(s);
   }


   const std::string dashLine("  --------------------------------------------------------------\n");


   // Note 5 - thread sync to wall clock
   // action: pauses a thread, resume thread action at next wall-clock-start-of-second
   void sleepToWallClockStartOfSec(std::time_t t0 = 0)
   {
      if (0 == t0) { t0 = std::time(nullptr); }
      while(t0 == std::time(nullptr))         {
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);  } // good-neighbor-thread
   }
   // a good-neighbor-thread delay does not 'hog' a processor


   // Note 4 - typedef examples to simplify
   // create new types based on vector ... suffix '_t' reminds that this is a type
   typedef std::vector<uint>           UintVec_t;
   typedef std::vector<uint>           TIDSeqVec_t;
   typedef std::vector<std::thread*>   Thread_pVec_t;


   // measure -std=C++14 std::thread average context switch duration
   //                                enforced with one PPLSem_t
   class Q6_t
   {
      // private data
      const uint        MaxThreads;        // thread count
      const uint        MaxSecs;           // seconds of test
      const std::string m_TIDSeqPFN;     // capture tid seq to ram (write to file later)
      //
      uint           m_thrdSwtchCount;   // count incremented by all threads
      //
      bool           m_done;             // main to threads: cease and desist
      uint           m_rdy;              // threads to main: thread is ready! (running)
      PPLSem_t       m_sem;              // one semaphore shared by all threads
      //
      UintVec_t      m_thrdRunCountVec;  // counts incremented per thread
      TIDSeqVec_t    m_TIDSeq_Vec;       // sequence (order) of thread execution
      Thread_pVec_t  m_thread_pVec;      // vector of thread pointers

   public:

      Q6_t()  // default ctor
         : MaxThreads(10)           // total threads
         , MaxSecs(10)              // controlled seconds of test
         , m_TIDSeqPFN("./Q6.txt")  // where put data file
           //
         , m_thrdSwtchCount(0)
           //
         , m_done(false)            // main() to threads: cease and desist
         , m_rdy(0)                 // threads to main(): thread is ready!
           // m_sem                 // default ctor ok
           //
           // m_thrdRunCountVec     // default ctor ok
           // m_TIDSeq_Vec          // default ctor ok
           // m_thread_pVec         // default ctor ok
         {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxThreads; ++i) {
               m_thrdRunCountVec.push_back(0);   // 0 each per-thread counter
            }
            // your results -----vvvvvvvv----will vary
            m_TIDSeq_Vec.reserve(45000000);  // observed as many as 42,000,000 on my old Dell
            m_thread_pVec.reserve(MaxThreads);
            // DO NOT start threads (m_thread_pVec) yet
         } // AciveObj_t()



      ~Q6_t()
         {
            // m_TIDSeq_Vec,
            while(m_thread_pVec.size()) {              // more to pop and delete
               std::thread* t = m_thread_pVec.back();  // return last element
               m_thread_pVec.pop_back();               // remove last element
               delete t;                               // delete thread
            }
            // m_thrdRunCountVec;
            // m_TIDSeqPFN, m_sem, m_rdy; m_done;
            // m_thrdSwtchCount; MaxSecs; MaxThreads;
         } // ~Q6_t()



      // Q6_t::main(..)  runs in context thread 'main()', invoked in function main()
      int main(std::string label)
         {
            std::cout << dashLine << "  " << MaxSecs << " second measure of "
                      << MaxThreads << " threads, 1 PPLSem_t " << label << "\n"
                      << "  output: " << m_TIDSeqPFN << '\n'<< std::endl;

            assert(0 == m_sem.lock());    // take posession of m_sem
            // now all thread will block at critical section entry (in onceThruCritSect())
            std::cout << "\n  block threads at crit sect   " << std::endl;

            createAndActivateThreads();

            long int durationUS = 0;

            releaseThreadsAndWait(durationUS); // run threads run

            std::cout << "\n" << std::endl
                      << report(" 'thread context switch' ",
                                m_thrdSwtchCount, durationUS);

            reportThreadActionCounts();

            writeTIDSeqToQ6_txt();

            reportMainStackSize();

            measure_LockUnlock();        // with no context switch, no collision

            return(0);
         } // int main() // in 'main' context


   private:


      void onceThru(uint id)  // a crit section
         {
            assert(0 == m_sem.lock());      // critical section entry
            {
               m_thrdSwtchCount      += 1;     // 'work'
               m_thrdRunCountVec[id] += 1;     // diagnostic - thread work-balance
               m_TIDSeq_Vec.push_back(id);     // thread sequence capture
            }
            assert(0 == m_sem.unlock());    // critical section exit
         }



      // thread entry point
      void threadRun(uint id)
         {
            std::cout << '.' << id << std::flush;  //  ".0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9"
            m_rdy |= (1 << id);     // thread to main: i am ready
            do {

               onceThru(id);

               if (m_done) break; // exit when done   tbr - FIXME -- rare hang

            }while(true);
         }



      // main() context: create and activate std::thread's with new
      void createAndActivateThreads() // main() context
         {
            std::cout << "  createAndActivateThreads()  ";
            Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();
            for (uint id = 0; id < MaxThreads; ++id)
            {
               // std::thread activates when instance created
               std::thread*  thrd = new
                  std::thread(&Q6_t::threadRun, this, id);
               // method-------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^--single param for method
               // instance*---------------------^^^^
               assert(nullptr != thrd);

               // create handshake mask for unique 'id' bit of m_rdy
               uint mask = (1 << id);

               // wait for bit set in m_rdy by thread
               while ( ! (mask & m_rdy) ) {
                  std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); // not a poll
               }
               // thread has confirmed to main() that it is running

               // capture pointer to invoke join's
               m_thread_pVec.push_back(thrd);
            }
            auto  duration_us =
               std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);
            std::cout << "   (" << digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
                      << " us)" << std::endl;

            sleepToWallClockStartOfSec(); // start-of-second

         } // void createAndActivateThreads()



      // main() context: measure average context switch duration
      //    by releasing threads to run
      void releaseThreadsAndWait(long int& count_us)
         {
            Time_t testStart_us = HRClk_t::now();

            // thread 'main()' is current owner of this semaphore - see "Q6_t::main()"
            assert(0 == m_sem.unlock()); // release the hounds

            std::cout << "  releaseThreadsAndWait        " << std::flush;

            // progress indicator to user
            for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxSecs; ++i) // let threads switch for 10 seconds
            {
               sleepToWallClockStartOfSec();    // 'main()' sync's to wall clock
               std::cout << (MaxSecs-i-1) << ' ' << std::flush; // "9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0"
            }

            // tbr - dedicated mutex for this single-write / multiple read ?  or std::atomic ?
            m_done = true;      // command threads to exit - all threads can see m_done

            auto  testDuration_us =
               std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - testStart_us);
            count_us = testDuration_us.count();

            // tbr - main() shall confirm all threads complete
            // tbr - measure how long to detect m_done


            Time_t joinStart_us = HRClk_t::now();
            std::cout << "\n  join threads                 ";
            for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxThreads; ++i)
            {
               m_thread_pVec[i]->join();           // main() waits here for thread[i] completion
               std::cout << ". " << std::flush;
            }
            auto  joinDuration_us =
               std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - joinStart_us);
            std::cout << "   (" << digiComma(std::to_string(joinDuration_us.count()))
                      << " us)" << std::endl;

         } // void releaseThreadsAndWait(long int& count_us)



      void reportThreadActionCounts()
         {
            std::cout << "\n  each thread run count: \n ";
            uint      sum = 0;
            for (auto it : m_thrdRunCountVec)
            {
               std::cout << std::setw(11) << digiComma(std::to_string(it));
               sum += it;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            uint diff = (sum - m_thrdSwtchCount);


            std::cout << ' ';
            double maxPC = 0.0;
            double minPC = 100.0;
            for (auto it : m_thrdRunCountVec)
            {
               double percent = static_cast<double>(it) / static_cast<double>(sum);
               if(percent > maxPC) maxPC = percent;
               if(percent < minPC) minPC = percent;
               std::cout << std::setw(11) << (percent * 100);
            }
            std::cout << "  (% of total)\n\n  total : " << digiComma(std::to_string(sum));

            if (diff) std::cout << "  (diff: " << diff << ")";

            std::cout << "   note variability --   min : " << (minPC*100)
                      << "%    max : " << (maxPC*100) << "%" << std::endl;
         } // void reportThreadActionCounts()



      void writeTIDSeqToQ6_txt() //  m_TIDSeq_Vec - record sequence of thread access to critsect
         {
            size_t sz = m_TIDSeq_Vec.size();
            std::cout << '\n' << dashLine << "  writing Thread ID sequence of "
                      << digiComma(std::to_string(sz)) << " values to "
                      << m_TIDSeqPFN << std::endl;

            Time_t writeStart_us = HRClk_t::now();

            do {
               std::ofstream Q6cout(m_TIDSeqPFN);

               if ( ! Q6cout.good() )
               {
                  std::cerr << "not able to open for write: " << m_TIDSeqPFN << std::endl;
                  break;
               }

               size_t lnSz = 0;
               for (auto it : m_TIDSeq_Vec)
               {
                  // encode Thread ID  uints:           0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
                  // to letters 'A' thru 'J': vvvvvv   'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J'
                  Q6cout << static_cast<char>(it+'A');
                  // whitespace not needed

                  if (++lnSz > 100) { Q6cout << std::endl; lnSz = 0; } // 100 chars per line
               }
               Q6cout << '\n' << std::endl;

               Q6cout.close();

            } while(0);

            auto wDuration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>
               ( HRClk_t::now() - writeStart_us );

            std::cout << "  complete: "
                      << digiComma(std::to_string(wDuration_us.count()))
                      << " us" << std::endl;
         } // writeTIDSeqToQ6_txt



      std::string report(std::string lbl, uint64_t eventCount, uint64_t duration_us)
         {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "  " << to_engineering_string(static_cast<double>(eventCount),9,eng_prefixed)
               << lbl << " events in " << digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us)) << " us" << std::endl;

            double eventsPerSec = (1000000.0*(static_cast<double>(eventCount))/
                                   static_cast<double>(duration_us));

            ss << "  " << to_engineering_string(eventsPerSec,9,eng_prefixed)
               << lbl << " events per second\n  "
               << to_engineering_string((1.0/eventsPerSec), 9, eng_prefixed)
               << " sec per " << lbl << " event " << std::endl;
            return(ss.str());
         } // std::string report(std::string lbl, uint64_t eventCount, uint64_t duration_us)


      // Note 6 - stack size -> use POSIX 'pthread_attr_...' API
      void reportMainStackSize()
         {
            pthread_attr_t tattr;
            int stat = pthread_attr_init (&tattr);
            assert(0 == stat);

            size_t size;
            stat = pthread_attr_getstacksize(&tattr, &size);
            assert(0 == stat);

            std::cout << '\n' << dashLine << "  Stack Size: "
                      << digiComma(std::to_string(size))
                      << "    [of 'main()' by pthread_attr_getstacksize]\n"
                      << std::endl;
            stat = pthread_attr_destroy(&tattr);
            assert(0 == stat);
         } // void reportMainStackSize()


      // Note 7 - semaphore API performance
      // measure duration when no context switch (i.e. no thread 'collision')
      void measure_LockUnlock()
         {
            //PPLSem_t*  sem1 = new PPLSem_t;
            //assert(nullptr != sem1);
            PPLSem_t sem1;
            size_t   count1 = 0;
            size_t   count2 = 0;
            std::cout << dashLine << "  3 second measure of lock()/unlock()"
                      << " (no collision) " << std::endl;
            time_t t0 = time(0) + 3;

            Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();
            do {
               assert(0 == sem1.lock());   count1 += 1;
               assert(0 == sem1.unlock()); count2 += 1;
               if(time(0) > t0)  break;
            }while(1);
            auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

            assert(count1 == count2);
            std::cout << report (" 'sem lock()+unlock()' ", count1, duration_us.count());

            std::cout << "\n";
         } // void mainMeasures_LockUnlock()

   };  // class Q6_t

} // namespace DTB


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   std::cout << "\nargc: " << argc << '\n' << std::endl;
   for (int i=0; i<argc; i+=1) std::cout  << argv[i] << "    ";
   std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
   {
      std::time_t t0 = std::time(nullptr);
      std::cout << "  " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&t0)) << std::endl;;
      DTB::sleepToWallClockStartOfSec(t0);
   }

   DTB::Time_t main_start_us = DTB::HRClk_t::now();
   int retVal = 0;
   {
      DTB::Q6_t  q6;
      retVal  =  q6.main(" Q6::main() ");
   }
   auto duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<DTB::US_t>
      (DTB::HRClk_t::now() - main_start_us);

   std::cout << "  FINI  "
             << DTB::digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
             << " us" << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

---

Typical Output on my Old Dell.

```
  Fri Jun 30 15:30:13 2017

  --------------------------------------------------------------
  10 second measure of 10 threads, 1 PPLSem_t  Q6::main() 
  output: ./Q6.txt


  block threads at crit sect   
  createAndActivateThreads()  .0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9   (1,002,120 us)
  releaseThreadsAndWait        9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
  join threads                 . . . . . . . . . .    (2,971 us)


  31.07730700 M 'thread context switch'  events in 10,021,447 us
  3.101079814 M 'thread context switch'  events per second
  322.4683207 n sec per  'thread context switch'  event 

  each thread run count: 
   3,182,496  3,252,929  3,245,473  3,150,344  3,411,918  2,936,982  2,978,690  3,029,319  3,004,926  2,884,230
     10.2406    10.4672    10.4432    10.1371    10.9788    9.45057    9.58478    9.74769     9.6692    9.28082  (% of total)

  total : 31,077,307   note variability --   min : 9.28082%    max : 10.9788%

  --------------------------------------------------------------
  writing Thread ID sequence of 31,077,307 values to ./Q6.txt
  complete: 3,025,289 us

  --------------------------------------------------------------
  Stack Size: 8,720,384    [of 'main()' by pthread_attr_getstacksize]

  --------------------------------------------------------------
  3 second measure of lock()/unlock() (no collision) 
  173.2359360 M 'sem lock()+unlock()'  events in 3,902,491 us
  44.39111737 M 'sem lock()+unlock()'  events per second
  22.52702926 n sec per  'sem lock()+unlock()'  event 

  FINI  18,957,304 us
```

---

Sample of Q6.txt   lines are 100 chars long.

```
AABABABABAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

---

last few lines

```
BJBJBJBJBJBJBJBJBBHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABABABAABABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBG
BGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBBHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBHBBHBHBHBHBBJJJJJJJJJ
JJJJJJJJJBBJBBBJBJBJBJBJBJBBJBJBJBJBJBJBJBJBJBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBBEBEBEBE
BEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBEBBEBEBEBBBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEBEBBEBEBEBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEBEBEBEBEEBEBEBEBEBBIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIBBIIIBIBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBFFBBFBFBFBFBFFBBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
BBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
GGBCIHFJDAE
```

Comment: > **All of the C functions you referenced are simply accessed by direct include.**
Thanks, I know that fact, but the task is in avoiding C and using C++ where it's possible. 
> **I measure durations by (...) counting how many times the loop completes.**
Could you explain this? Are you ignoring the time of process running? Is it minor in contrast with the time of switching?

Comment: And how are you excluding the influence of other OS tasks?

Comment: Good questions.  I am preparing a second (brief) answer to address these comments, which I will "Add Another Answer" to this posting, hopefully today.

Comment: "...but the task is in avoiding C" -- Perhaps you might think of the functions like "popen", "usleep", "clock_gettime", "time", ; and the posix functions ("pthread_create", "pthread_join") collectively as a Linux API.  These functions are neither "C" code nor C++ ...they are simply the API any program must use to interact with Linux.  I suspect other languages use them, too.

Answer (score 1):

> > All of the C functions you referenced are simply accessed by
> >     direct include.
>
> Thanks, I know that fact, but the task is in avoiding C and using
>   C++ where it's possible.

My C++ code has no C code in it, it simply invokes the extern "C"
functions that Linux provides.  There is no separate set of C++ Linux
function calls.  The Linux API (to the os services) is defined by the
C library and header files. I know of no way to avoid or work around
the Linux API, so perhaps I do not know what you are suggesting / asking.

> > I measure durations by repeating some action for 1 to 10 seconds,
> >     and counting how many times the loop completes.
>
> Could you explain this?

consider the snippet

```
{
  uint64_t microsecStart = getSystemMicroSecond();

    //convert linear time to broken-down/calendar time
    local_tm = *localtime_r (&linear_time, &local_tm); 

    uint64_t microsecDuration = getSystemMicroSecond() - microsecStart;
}
```

This operation is typically too fast to measure in this simple manner,
essentially a delta-microsecond, The conversion would be over before a
microsecond might change.

To measure something this quick, we spin around the action of
interest, and count the loops, and kick out after, say 3 seconds.

```
uint64_t microsecStart = getSystemMicroSecond();
uint32_t loopCount = 0;
time_t t0 = time(0) + 3; // loop for < 3 seconds
do
{   
   //convert linear time to broken-down/calendar time
   local_tm = *localtime_r (&linear_time, &local_tm); 

   time_t t1 = time(0);
   if(t1 != t0) break;
   loopCount += 1;

} while(1);
uint64_t microsecDuration = getSystemMicroSecond() - microsecStart;
```

In this loop, the time(0) function is surprisingly quick.

- time(0) takes ~75 nano seconds (on my Dell desktop)

so time(0) does not significantly extend the measurement.

But is quick enough to make an accurate measurement of local time duration

- localtime_r takes ~335 nano seconds

When these spins complete, the test has created a loopCount, and a
duration measurement outside the loop provides a more consistent measurement
of duration ..., and from those we can then compute an 'average'
duration for each event.

> Are you ignoring the time of process running?

Yes. Because I know that a context switch is 2 orders of
  magnitude slower than a function call, it is not difficult
  to minimize the thread activity to have no/minimal influence
  on the measurement.

> Is it minor in contrast with the time of switching?

In this test, the threads increment a number, tests a flag, and acts
  as a good neighbor (i.e. these threads surrender the processor as
  soon as possible).  These minor actions are insignificant to the
  cost of a context switch.

The numbers for my 6 yr old Dell are 3 orders of magnitude difference.

simple function call: i.e. time(0)    < 75 e-9 seconds

thread context switch                 < 15 e-6 seconds
  enforced with semaphore

Other activities can influence the results, but I think in an
insignificant way.  My result of 14 us per "thread switch and
semaphore send" is longer than the best possible result, but not
enough longer to influence my design decisions.  It is possible to
improve this measurement, but I can't afford the hardware.

Linux provides some thread or task priority ideas, but I have not
explored them.  When I'm serious about finding a 'better' measurement,
I guess I would disconnect the ethernet, close any busy work...  but
I'm not running compiles nor copying files nor running a backup nor
any obvious cpu cycle consumer when I'm measuring.  The machine is
substantially idle.  Just clock ticks, timers expiring, memory
refresh, and a few other things that must continue.

For fun or interest, you might pull up the System Monitor utility,
click on the %CPU tag 1 or 2 times, and bring the busiest task to the
top ... you should find that the busiest task is, ta-da: the system
monitor at maybe 3 % of one of the 2 cpu's.  All other tasks are
essentially waiting for something, and trigger 0% of load.

Finally you might think of it this way...

are you writing a program to run on an atypical machine?
  or is your target similar to your development machine?

Do you plan to shut off interrupts? i/o channels? ethernet? control
  priority?  or is your target going to be useful.

IMHO, the running tasks in my useful (linux) system, when the system is
not doing anything but waiting for my next keystroke, are generally
doing nothing for most of a 10 second test.

I think the most important takeaway from these efforts is that:

```
 function calls are more than 100x faster than context switches.
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the Linux API (to the os services) is designed for superior performance.  With that in mind, it is reasonable for the simpler API's to be implemented in assembly.  And when implemented in assembly does not make any part of my code in any way assembly.  The API defines how to invoke the code, and its implementation does not 'taint' the use of another language, such as C++.