# Is my C++ code to measure context switch time correct?

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote the C++ code below to measure the time for context switching on Linux. I got the result 3.98757e-06 second, which seems much longer than I expected.

Can anyone tell me if my code is correct? ( My computer has 4 processors which are 1199, 2534, 3072, 1199 MHz respectively and I am not sure if this information related ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

bool flag = false;
int counter = 0;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable setCV, unsetCV;
time_t timer1 = time(NULL);
time_t timer2 = timer1;

void setFlag(){
    unique_lock<mutex> lk( mtx );
    while( flag ){
        setCV.wait( lk );
    }

    flag = true;
    counter++;
    unsetCV.notify_one();
}

void unsetFlag(){
    unique_lock<mutex> lk( mtx );
    while( !flag ){
        unsetCV.wait( lk );
    }

    flag = false;
    counter++;
    setCV.notify_one();
}

void setAgent(){
    while( difftime( timer2, timer1 ) < 1 ){
        setFlag();
        timer2 = time( NULL );
    }
}

void unsetAgent(){
    while( difftime( timer2, timer1 ) < 1 ){
        unsetFlag();
        timer2 = time( NULL );
    }
}

int main(){
    thread iThread = thread( setAgent );
    thread dThread = thread( unsetAgent );
    iThread.join();
    dThread.join();
    cout << (float) 1 / counter << endl;
}
```

I noticed the post [How to measure a time of switching process context in Linux using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145872/how-to-measure-a-time-of-switching-process-context-in-linux-using-c), but no code is there.

Comment: No. You're assuming that dThread will get scheduled immediately after iThread - you cannot guarantee this at all. You're also including the time taken for the kernel to deal with all the mutexes etc in your calculation.

Comment: You're using flag as a lock for `counter`, I think.  But you're not telling the compiler about the memory ordering requirement you need it to have.  On x86 it probably happens to work as you intend, but you should use `atomic<bool> flag` and do `while(! flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire)){ loop body; }  counter++;  flag.store(false, std:memory_order_release);`.  (In that order, not the broken order you're using where you flip the flag *before* modifying the data your lock protects.  Or are you also doing the same thing with the mutex?)

Comment: A few microseconds for context switching seems reasonable these days.

Comment: So there is not a easy way to roughly calculate the context switch time without knowing the scheduling algorithm ( according to  slugonamission's comment), right? Is anyone aware of any such code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Untill C11 `time()` returns the seconds since 01/01/1970 00:00 UTC as an integral value. Your results make me assume, that you are using C11 or above, since then `time_t` is a floating point value. ([see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t)) Anyway, the Standard does not give you any guarantees about the precission and the runtime of `time()`. you'd have to subtract that.
2. Your assumptions on the way the scheduler will decide to run your second thread are not reliable. The best thing you can do is to use CPU-shielding, but I wouldn't count on the results even then. Make a lot of measurements, drop the 10% highest and lowest results, take the average. That might give a close enough and rather stable figure.

Comment: Thanks to [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)  `time` or `clock_gettime` is not really a system call (that is, does not require switching to kernel mode) on recent Linux. On my i3770K machine it takes less than 4 nanoseconds.

Comment: The vdso(7) man page tells us, that `clock_gettime()` is part of that library, but it does not name `time()`. On the other hand, syscall(2) says, that `time()` is a syscall. I assume, that you have better information. Please share, where I can find it.